# Create child using existing record abstract class

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, abstract-class

I have the class `Person` with the fields:

- **PersonID (PK)**
- Name
- First Name

And the class `Member` with the fields:

- **PersonID (FK & PK)**
- Function
- Member since

`Member` inherits from `Person`. So in the database it also has the fields `Name` and `First Name`.

When I directly create a member, I give all the data in textboxes and send it to the database. The database automatically creates a person when I create member, which is good. **But**, when I have an existing person I want to use this data to create a member, like upgrading the person, but without the database creating a new person record because that's not needed because I already have the person record.

How is this done in `C# and MVC`?

PS: `DBMS is SQL Server 2008`

Comment: I think irrespective of whether it is mvc or not, how are you updating the database? Is it through a stored procedure directly being called or is it through EF or Linq-to-sql, etc?

Comment: @samar It's through EF and it can happen that we use Linq-to-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want to implement insert/update query using [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) clause. It may look like:

```
MERGE Members AS t
USING 
    (
        SELECT  @person_id person_id,                           
    ) AS s
    ON t.person_id = s.person_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
        (
            person_id,
            name,
            ...
        )
    VALUES
        (
            s.person_id,
            @name,
            ...
        );
```

So when you pass `@person_id` variable with value 0 or null or any other non-existing in database you'll get new record, otherwise, if `@person_id` matches with any record in db, it'll be updated